# Get raw HTML in servlet to churn out a PDF file

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets, pdf

I have a JSP which is rendered after it is forwarded from a servlet. Now that I have a HTML from JSP I want to post this page in order to generate a PDF.

As per my understanding the submit button only submits a form. But, I need to submit raw HTML to eventually use FlyingSaucer or similiar PDF creator library.

What is the way to use my HTML and then save the PDF to a file?

Please chime in to correct if I am wrong and what you think about my approach. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Sorry I have posted no code but at the moment I have hit a wall in the servlet in my quest to get around this.

Comment: One solution is to send your html code using javascript,you will send all your html document in a variable to your servlet,with ajax or using hidden field in a form

Comment: @FaceOfJock: note that it's not possible to download files with ajax. So returning whole PDF on that would not be possible.

Comment: @BalusC what i mean ,is that he will pass sourceCode and then calls exportPDF method from his servlet using $.POST.Servlet's method will do the rest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've basically 2 options:

1. Let JS set the current HTML DOM tree as a (hidden) request parameter on submit.

   ```html
   <form method="post" action="pdfservlet">
       <input type="hidden" name="source" />
       <input type="submit" value="generate" onclick="this.form.source.value = document.documentElement.outerHTML;" />
   </form>
   ```

   It's in `pdfservlet` available as `request.getParameter("source")`.
2. Let `pdfservlet` request the desired page programmatically using `URL`/`URLConnection`.

   ```
   InputStream source = new URL("http://localhost:8080/context/someservlet").openStream();
   // ...
   ```

   Set if necessary `JSESSIONID` cookie with current session ID if you need it to run in same session.

   ```
   URLConnection connection = new URL("http://localhost:8080/context/someservlet").openConnection();
   connection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", "JSESSIONID=" + request.getSession().getId());
   InputStream source = connection.getInputStream();
   // ...
   ```